# Using Appcode with Kotlin/Native and Cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, appcode, kotlin-native

I'm starting to use Kotlin/native and Appcode for iOS development. I'm trying to get Cocoapods to work with Kotlin/native, but I'm having some challenges.

I've started with the empty Kotlin/native application in AppCode and built that, it builds fine and runs in the Emulator.

Then I try to add Cocoapods with "AFNetworking" I run into trouble. I have tried to follow the JetBrains Kotlin/native sample : https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/tree/master/samples/cocoapods , but still no luck.

The problems that I'm facing is :

- I'm not able to import the cocoapods.AFNetworking in my Kotlin file.
- I'm getting the following error when I try to build the project : "Cannot perform cinterop processing for AFNetworking: cannot determine headers location."

I might have overlooked some configurations, but I cant't figure it out.

I'm using Appcode 2019.3.1 , Xcode 11.3(11C29) and Cocoapods 1.8.4

My Podfile looks like this :
[image: Podfile]

My Gradle file looks like this : [image: build.gradle.kts]

My main.kt file looks like this : [image: main.kt]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to build the project from Xcode first.

Generate the podspec using the `podspec` gradle task and modify that accordingly then add that to your `Podfile`

```
target 'project' do
    ...
    pod 'YourFrameworkName', :path => 'path/to/your-kotlin-library'
end
```

You could check it here:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/cocoapods.html#interoperability

Edit:

Also, here's a sample of a Kotlin/Native using `AFNetworking` in the Kotlin code. https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/tree/master/samples/cocoapods

Edit 2:

Again, you have to link the K/N project to your Xcode Project and build it there.

Step 1: Add the pod to your Gradle file

```
kotlin {
    cocoapods {
        ...
        pod("AFNetworking")
    }
}
```

Step 2: Generate the podspec file through `./gradlew shared-module:podspec`

This will generate the podspec file which you might have to modify before building.

Step 3: Use this in your `Podfile`

```
target 'project' do
    ...
    pod 'YourFrameworkName', :path => 'path/to/your-kotlin-library'
end
```

Step 4: `pod install`
Step 5: Build it in Xcode

After that, you'll be able to reference it in K/N by importing `cocoapods.AFNetworking.*`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. From what I can see from the link you provided it's for importing a Kotlin/Native lib into a Xcode project. I'm looking for using a Cocoapods library 'AFNetworking' in a Kotlin/Native project : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/cocoapods.html#interoperability.

Comment: My bad for the link. I updated the link to the correct docs. Please take a look.

Comment: Yes, I have used that sample as an inspiration for my test. I have still difficulties with getting the AFNetworking to be imported correctly. Kotlin will still not let me do "import cocoapods.AFNetworking" , and I still get this error when building : "Cannot perform cinterop processing for AFNetworking: cannot determine headers location." . This leads me to believe that there is something missing with cinterop config ?

Comment: You have to build it in Xcode first before you'll be able to use it in K/N. I've updated my answer above with steps.

Comment: I've followed your instruction and also can't make import cocoapods.AFNetworking to work. I'm using kotlin 1.3.61, Xcode 11.3

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the instructions Kurt. I tried to follow them , but still run into problems.

1. Starting new project in Appcode ( test1) , build ok in  Appcode. Opening same project in Xcode , builds ok.
2. Adds the Cocoapod plugin reference and  the pod to my Gradle file and also sets version= "1.0"
3. Runs the podspec task
4. Issues "pod setup" , and "pod init"
5. Adds the pod enty into the Podfile : "pod 'test1', :path => '/Users/trond/Desktop/test1/test1'" . (This comes from the output of podspec)
6. Issues "pod install"
7. Reopens Xcode with project : "test1.xcworkspace' and tries to build. It fails with a permision error on "gradlew"
8. Fixing permisions on "gradlew" with "chmod 777 gradlew"
9. Tries to build with Xcode again, it fails with : "Project 'test1' not found in root project 'test1' . The task that fails is : "$REPO_ROOT/../Supporting Files/gradlew" -p "$REPO_ROOT" :test1:syncFramework                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.target=$KOTLIN_TARGET                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.configuration=$CONFIGURATION                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.cflags="$OTHER_CFLAGS"                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.paths.headers="$HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS"                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.paths.frameworks="$FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS""

$REPO_ROOT = PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT =/Users/trond/Desktop/test1/Pods/../test1

Comment: I solved this error by going into the test1.podspec file and remove the "test1" before :syncFramwork.

When trying to build now in Xcode I get the familiar error : 
"Cannot perform cinterop processing for AFNetworking: cannot determine headers location"